# convert a list/tuple of int strings to int

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, csv, numpy

I have a bit of code and i need to do .data on a list. However, the intable strings cannot take the .data and i need to convert them to integers. Yes, I know this is duplicate but the other questions say do it manually and this list is far too big. How would I do this? Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
from tabulate import tabulate
from csv import DictReader

digits = pandas.read_csv('C:/Users/saeed/Downloads/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv')

print(tabulate(digits, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))

with open('C:/Users/saeed/Downloads/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv') as i:
    price = [row["price"] for row in DictReader(i)]
    print(price)

clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100)

x,y = price.data[:1], price.target[:1]
```

error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. `price` is just an ordinary list read from the CSV file, it's not a numpy object.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are reading the CSV with two different methods: pandas and Dictreader.  You already have the data in `digits`.  `price = list(digits.price)` would work without the DictReader code, or just `print(digits.price)` if you want to view that column of the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
price = [row["price"] for row in DictReader(i)]
```

and changing it to:

```
price = [int(row["price"]) for row in DictReader(i)]
```

should be enough.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. However, I am still getting the same error. Is there a way to convert this list into a bunch of ints themselves? Or does a different data type have the data attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Try replace your with statement with

```
for i in digits:
    price = [int(row["price"]) for row in DictReader(i)]
    print(price)
```

Comment: @Darksp33d did you get it working? If so please mark my answer as correct so people in the future can fix this issue!